# How to run a python script from an MQL4 EA-process ( MetaTrader4 Terminal )?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

I have a simple `test.py` script that I would like to run from an MQL4 EA.

How can I implement this?

I have tried using **`ShellExecute()`** but that will not work in my case as I am running MetaTrader4 Terminal on a linux machine and thus cannot call windows based `ShellExecute()` ( even with a `wine` ).

Answer (score 0):

## Option 0: use of a `wine`-promise to have a full DLL-abstraction

The `wine` project, if configured properly, ought provide a full DLL-abstraction, so that a legitimate `ShellExecute()` ought provide a way to launch a wine-enveloped MetaTrader4 Terminal a launch of such intended process.

---

## Option 1: use a distributed processing { ZeroMQ | nanomsg }

Given this option feasible since ZeroMQ v2.11, the python was always ready to communicate with MQL4 and start/stop any service provisioning on-`{MQL4|*}`-demand. This would be my preferred way, as the workflow is not isolated to just "fire-and-forget" missile-control.

Using this architecture many years for AI/ML-predictor Predictive Engine, Remote Keyboards, off-site centralised smart-logging, process-health/performance-telemetry services integration ( not only with MQL4-code execution-units ) and remaining happy all the years for having chosen this advanced distributed architecture way.

---

<sub>**Nota Bene:** It is fair to note, that somewhere around an MQL4 Build 850 / 900 MetaTrader4 Terminal code-execution engine revision has created a few dozens headbang issues for DLL-wrapper / original ZeroMQ v2.11 wrapper, but some moderate amount of efforts made the *New-*`MQL4.56789` change of `string`, which stopped to be **`string`** anymore ( being surprisingly a re-dressed **`struct`** ), but in most high-performance processing interactions are bit-packed, so no heart-breaks ought appear from this.</sub>

---

### Python side:

```
def main():
    # setup ZeroMQ infrastructure and map all resources
    import  zmq
    ...
    pass; mainloopSTAY = True
    #     mainloop(): -----------------------------
    while mainloopSTAY:
       try:
           # ----------------------- event-handling:
           pass;   
       except:
           # ------------------------- EXC-handling: { continue }
           pass;
       finally:
           # dismantle ZeroMQ infrastructure and release all resources
           pass;   print( "INF: main().finally: EXIT" )
           # { break | if mainloopSTAY }
    #----------------------------------------------
    pass;          print( "INF: main().pre-return SECTION" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()   #  EXECUTED only if this module-file was called to run from a command-line ( Ref. SECTION: import for def: )
```

---

### MQL4 side:

```
#include   <mql4zmq_for_Terminal_4.00_Build.840.mqh>        // STILL BUG/ERROR on zmq_poll() while missing zmq_poll_struct_t

         string   aTemp = ">>> ";                           // globally visible ...
         int      aZmqCONTEXT,                              // globally visible ...
                  aZmqSOCKET;                               // globally visible ... so as to be able to auto-deinit in { EA -s | #Indicators } .deinit() on panic termination(s)

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|      msMOD_deinit( int       aZmqSOCKET  = EMPTY )               |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void     msMOD_deinit( const int aZmqSOCKET  = EMPTY ) {
         if (                    aZmqSOCKET != EMPTY ) {
               zmq_setsockopt(   aZmqSOCKET, ZMQ_LINGER, 0 );
               zmq_close(        aZmqSOCKET );
               }
         zmq_term(               aZmqCONTEXT );
         return;
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void  OnDeinit( const int anAutoDeinitREASON ){ // auto-generated ONLY for { EA-s , #Indicator-s }
      msMOD_deinit( aZmqSOCKET );
   }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void  OnStart()
{                                      aZmqCONTEXT = zmq_init(1);                            // .init into globally visible int
                                 if (  aZmqCONTEXT < 0 ){   
                                                            msMOD_deinit();                  // GRACEFUL CLEANUP
                                                            return;                          // DEBUG: RET()
                                 }
                                 int   aZmqPAIR = zmq_socket( aZmqCONTEXT, ZMQ_PAIR );       // .sock PAIR
                                 if (  aZmqPAIR < 0 ){
                                                            msMOD_deinit( aZmqPAIR );        // GRACEFUL CLEANUP
                                                            return;                          // DEBUG: RET()
                                 }
                                 int   aZmqBindPAIR = zmq_bind(   aZmqPAIR,
                                                                  "tcp://A.B.C.D:PORT"  // i5-eth0-IP:#####
                                                                  );                     
                                 if (  aZmqBindPAIR < 0 ){
                                                            msMOD_deinit( aZmqPAIR );        // GRACEFUL CLEANUP
                                                            return;                          // DEBUG: RET()
                                 }
       ...
       int RC = mql4zmq_msg_init_data( aSendMsgOBJ, aSendMsgBuffUCHAR, aSendMsgBUFF_SIZE * 4 );
       zmq_send( aZmqPAIR,             aSendMsgOBJ );
       ...
}
```

---

Comment: Sorry, but this doesnt help me that much. Prior to asking this question on stackoverflow, I did my research and found multiple wrappers like ZeroMQ but couldnt find a simple solution to simply running a python script from them. Could you provide a working example?

Comment: Sure, it works like a charm. Python script process starts first, having a prepared a `.bind()`-RTO service end-point and idles in an event-loop or some form of multi-threaded service-monitor. The MQL4-side freely `connect()`-s to this once it starts and if it wants some python interaction ( even being that the "fire-and-forget" one ), it asks python, using this very Signalling / Messaging layer. A reversed-`{ .bind() | .connect() }` scenario is also possible, where needed, so only one's own imagination is the ceiling. If one can integrate on ZeroMQ inside python, MQL4 is ( almost ) for free.

Comment: I appreciate it. I wanted to know how to simply execute a python script from my EA. Simply executing a .py file from MQL4. I feel like this is a bit more advanced than what I want to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, man, the World can be complicated and often is. Look, you have received full set of two different approaches, each of which works for reaching the indicated goal. You have even received the full code-examples, to follow with and just assemble your specific parts of the solution into each of the code-templates. Shouting "Any ideas?" on Community members, that were keen doing their best to help you achive is neither polite, not constructive, is it?. **So where is the problem?** Any ideas?